# count of duplicate records by passing dynamic table name and colum names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, duplicates, sql-delete

Thanks for all your help in Advance.

I have requirement to find is there any duplicates exits or not in all the tables (more than 100).

I know the SQL to find out the duplicates by table by table but Is there anyway we can pass colu and table as dynamically run the sql.

table name and key col needs to passed dynamically

step1 : SQL to get the all the table names and associated key col
step2 : run the duplicates query 
select
col1,col2,....col5
count(1)
FROM
schema.tablename
group by col1,col2...col 5
having count(1) > 1

can some please help me to avoid the manual stuff to run manually by cols and tablenames manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could build your SQL script using `*_TAB_COLUMNS` view and `LISTAGG`.

For example:

```
select 
  'select '||listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_name)||
  ' from '||table_name||' 
   group by '||listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_name)||' 
   having count(*) >1 ' str
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
group by table_name;
```

The output of the above query for `EMPLOYEES` table in `HR` schema(*of course formatted the SQL)*:

```
SELECT
    commission_pct,
    department_id,
    email,
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    hire_date,
    job_id,
    last_name,
    manager_id,
    phone_number,
    salary
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    commission_pct,
    department_id,
    email,
    employee_id,
    first_name,
    hire_date,
    job_id,
    last_name,
    manager_id,
    phone_number,
    salary
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

To loop through all the tables in the schema and generate it for all tables, you could do something like:

```
DECLARE
  TABLE_COLUMNS VARCHAR2(10000);
  DELETE_STATEMENT VARCHAR2(10000);
  CURSOR ALL_MY_TABLES IS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES);
BEGIN
  FOR MY_TABLE IN ALL_MY_TABLES 
  LOOP
    -- prepare the list of columns
    SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) INTO TABLE_COLUMNS FROM 
        USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
    -- prepare the delete statements
    DELETE_STATEMENT := 'DELETE FROM ' || YOUR_TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ROWID NOT IN 
        (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM ' || YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
         || ' GROUP BY ' || TABLE_COLUMNS ||');';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DELETE_STATEMENT;
    -- output of all delete statements in loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DELETE_STATEMENT);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: not sure how to pass dynamically as I am not familiar with pl sql scripting. can I more detail info

Comment: You have everything that you asked for in the answer. Just go through it to understand. It's just a matter of copy pasting and executing it.